# Format(CDate()) result giving Wrong Results

Tags: vb.net

i Have the followin code in vb

```
Dim sStart As String, sEnd As String
sStart = ComboBoxYear.List(ComboBoxYear.ListIndex) & "-" & ComboBoxMonth.List(ComboBoxMonth.ListIndex) & "-1"

sEnd = Format(DateAdd("M", 1, CDate(sStart)) - 1, "yyyy-MMM-dd")
```

Now i have changed this in VB.NET as

```
sStart = Me.ComboBoxYear.SelectedItem.ToString() & "-" & ComboBoxMonth.SelectedItem.ToString() & "-1"
sEnd = Format(DateAdd("M", 1, CDate(sStart)) & -1, "yyyy-MMM-dd")
```

But **sEnd** giving  result as  'yyyy-MMM-dd' only, what i did wrong in my code.

Answer (score 0):

Try Like This

```
sStart = Me.ComboBoxYear.SelectedItem.ToString() & "-" & 
ComboBoxMonth.SelectedItem.ToString() & "-1"
sEnd =Format(CDate(DateAdd("M", 1, CDate(sStart)) & -1), "yyyy-MMM-dd")
```

Add CDate inside of `DateAdd("M", 1, CDate(sStart)) & -1`

Comment: I changed my code as -- >  sEnd = Format(DateAdd("M", 1, CDate(sStart)), "yyyy-MMM-dd")    .   Now it is working fine.  your code still resulting only 'yyyy-MMM-dd'. any way thanks for Reply.

Comment: @user3463529 where you changed. above code is working fine for me